# Format an existing Excel file sheets with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I receive some reports in an xslx file that has 2 sheets, the data is good but there's no formatting done on the file. Most of the posts I found talk about formatting the file while creating it, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can work the file with c# code after receiving it (ex : fit columns to content)?
Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClosedXML;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.Excel;

namespace ExcelFormatter
{
    class MainScript
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = args[0];

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Excel.Range chartRange;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(file);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "F1");
            chartRange.Cells.Font.Bold = true;

            xlWorkBook.Save();
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, file, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm

Comment: If i think i've understood your question well, the answer is yes, you can get your excel data and format it the way you prefer with c#. Use the Microsoft Excel Object Libray. Here's some sample code and a tutorial you migh find useful: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm. It was for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to manipulate Excel files that have been created using the OpenXML standard.  It found it to be easy to use and allowed me to do a lot of things to my documents.  Hope this helps.

Wade

Here is an example of what I have done.  It is in VB.Net, but you should be able to convert it with no problem.

```
'Open the workbook and then open the worksheet I want to work with.
Dim workbook = New XLWorkbook("<filepath>")
Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheet("<worksheetname>")

' Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
If worksheet Is Nothing Then
    Throw New ArgumentException("Sheet is missing")
End If

'Set number formatting.  You can look at the closedxml documentation to see what the number should be
worksheet.Cell("G5").Style.NumberFormat.SetNumberFormatId(1)

'Merge and style a group of cells
Dim cellRange = "A1:A12"
worksheet.Range(cellRange).Merge.Value = colName
worksheet.Range(cellRange).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black
worksheet.Range(cellRange).Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White
worksheet.Range(cellRange).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center

'Auto adjust the column widths      
worksheet.Columns.AdjustToContents()

workbook.SaveAs("<filename>")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to do the same thing, the program compile but my file doesn't change, I tried to put the first columns as Bold just to test the code but it's not working. (I've added the code to my initial post)

Comment: Actually it works, I tried to use save instead of SaveAS, and that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) to import the xlsx file and after that to apply the format that you need:

```
// Create an instance of the class that imports XLSX files
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();

// Import XLSX file
workbook.easy_LoadXLSXFile(filePath);

// Get the table of data from the first sheet
ExcelTable xlsTable = ((ExcelWorksheet)workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0)).easy_getExcelTable();

// Create the formatting style for cells
ExcelStyle xlsStyle = new ExcelStyle();
xlsStyle.setHorizontalAlignment(Alignment.ALIGNMENT_LEFT);
xlsStyle.setForeground(Color.DarkGray);

//Apply the formatting to A1 cell
xlsTable.easy_getCell(0, 0).setStyle(xlsStyle);

// Resave the XLSX file
workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile(newFormattedFilePath);
```

Check this link on [formatting Excel cells](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/format-excel-cells.html) fro more specific details.